# How can I generate a document from a single word using GPT or BERT?

Tags: natural-language-processing, bert, language-model, gpt

I have a dataset of 100000 documents each labelled with a topic to it. I want to create a model such that, given a topic, the model can generate a document from it.

I came across language models [GPT](https://s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/openai-assets/research-covers/language-unsupervised/language_understanding_paper.pdf), GPT-2 and [BERT](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1810.04805.pdf). I learned that they can be used for generation purposes. But I did not find anywhere whether they can generate sentences given only a word.

I am inclined to use GPT for my task, but I am not sure how to proceed with it. I wanted to know whether it is possible or not? It would be helpful if anyone can help me give a start in the right direction.

Comment: Why rely on models like GPT and do it manually from the array?

Comment: Because I want to leverage the linguistics knowledge of the pre-trained models and just fine tune it to my specific task.